# Magento 1.9.0.1 to 2.2.6 data-migration issue

Tags: magento2, data-migration

Magento data-migration process all done and all data showing but products add and edit feature not working. when we click on product edit action then we will face issue check below error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
>   must be of the type array, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php
>   on line 220 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:172

Stack trace:

```
#0 /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(220): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('file_upload', NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(84): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('file_upload', 'jvs_file', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(159): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare()
#3 /var/www/html/magentofirst/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(156): Mag" while reading response header from upstream, client: 43.240.9.243, server: magentofirst.com, request: "POST /ehplabsc_admin/catalog/product/reload/type/simple/store/0/popup/1/componentJson/1/prev_set_id/16/key/23b5e695b6a69fb96cd248a624282baaea5126f0c9a7e9e8232087140eb6ac42/?set=11&isAjax=true HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "http://magentofirst.com", referrer: "http://magentofirst.com/ehplabsc_admin/catalog/product/new/set/16/type/simple/key/6b13831a073eed316c24f915474fcd0f361293882a5ca0ef1898742a51d1777f/"
```

Comment: Have a look at it 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209315/magento-migration-product-error-uicomponentfactory-argumentsresolvercreated/241149

Comment: I have tried it but still facing same issue

Comment: Not sure about the issue, you can check the products in catalog_product_entity table to ensure whether the data is migrated properly or not.
select count(*) from catalog_product_entity;