# Clicking on product (Edit option) from ADMIN is throwing a -----"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError argumentsResolver('created_by)'"

Tags: magento2, admin, error, product-attribute, magento2.3

The problem is the same as here,[[Magento migration product error: UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('created_by', NULL)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209315/magento-migration-product-error-uicomponentfactory-argumentsresolvercreated/241149][1])

but it has not solved my problem. everyone have any other solutions?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to 
Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver()
must be of the type array, null given, called in 
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 222 and defined in 
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:174 Stack trace: #0 
/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(222):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('created_by', NULL)
 #1 /vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(85):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('created_by', '', Array)
 #2 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(164):
 Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare() 
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(161): 
Magent in /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 174
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign a required field to solve my problem

[image]