# Fatal error when editing the custom theme pls check

Tags: magento2, design

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory::argumentsResolver() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 222 and defined in /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(222): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver('header_logo_src', NULL) #1 /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Form/Field.php(85): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('header_logo_src', 'imageploader', Array) #2 /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(164): Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field->prepare() #3 /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiCo in /var/www/html/sat/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php on line 174
```

Comment: Please refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/209315) link.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

And then check.